# Differentiation under an integral sign

Tags: integration, derivatives

I found this integral in a solution of heat equation: 
$$I(b)=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-z^2}\cos(bz)dz$$
Differentiating in b, 
$$I'(b)=\int_{0}^{\infty}(-ze^{-z^2})\sin(bz)dz$$

How is the differentiation done in the integral sign ? This looks too simple. But is it correct?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Proof_of_basic_form if you're unconvinced.

Comment: Thanks man. Solved it using Leibniz integral. I totally forgot about it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints: apply DCT. By MVT we have $\frac {e^{-z^{2}}-e^{-z^{2}}} {z-z'} =-2t e^{-t^{2}}$ for some $t$ between $z$ and $z'$. But  $|-2t e^{-t^{2}}| \leq 2e^{-(z-1)^{2}} (z+1)$ if $|z-z'| <1$. Now show that $2e^{(z-1)^{2}} (z+1)$ is integrable. (Of course $\cos (bz)$ is bounded). Now DCT gives the justification.